# The type or namespace name 'DataException' could not be found

Tags: .net-core

I am getting the following compilation error using .NET Core 1.0:

> “The type or namespace name 'DataException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)”, code: CS0246.

### project.json

```
 {
  "name": "Dna.Net.Core",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Autofac": "4.1.0",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.1.0",
    "System.Runtime": "4.1.0",
    "System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters": "4.0.0-rc3-24212-01",
    "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives": "4.1.1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

[corefx: System.Data.SqlClient](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/0487c20a45ce46e48748227de43d6d929d839fee/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System.Data.SqlClient.csproj#L10)

```
48  <Compile Include="System\Data\DataException.cs" />
```

### IDataExceptionMessageHandler.cs

```
using Dna.Net.Core.Common;
using System.Data;

namespace Dna.Net.Core.Exceptions
{
    public partial interface IDataExceptionMessageHandler
    {
        CustomMessage Execute(DataException exception);
        CustomMessage ParseMessage(DataException exception, CustomMessage customMessage);
        void LogException(string message);
    }
}
```

Does .NET Core 1.0 support System\Data\DataException.cs?

Answer (score 1):

The file is there but it doesn't have DataException class -https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/DataException.cs

It doesnt support.